# How to set the Glue Crawler RecrawlPolicy in my CF template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I would like to set my glue crawler to only crawl new folders in my s3 bucket. Based on documentation, it looks like I want to set the RecrawlBehavior to [CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling-RecrawlPolicy). But I can't find any guidance on how to do that in a CloudFormation template.

This is my crawler's configuration property now, but my use of RecrawlBehavior is invalid:

```
Configuration: "{\"Version\":1.0,\"RecrawlBehavior\":\"CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY\",\"CrawlerOutput\":{\"Partitions\":{\"AddOrUpdateBehavior\":\"InheritFromTable\"},\"Tables\":{\"AddOrUpdateBehavior\":\"MergeNewColumns\"}}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, Incremental policy is a relatively new feature in Glue and not supported in Cloud Formation yet.

A workaround I can suggest to overcome this limitation is creating a crawler using cloudformation and then use AWS CLI to update its RecrawlPolicy property.

When you create a crawler using cloudformation and try to retrieve its properties using CLI, RecrawlPolicy" has "RecrawlBehavior" set to "CRAWL_EVERYTHING". You can use the below command to change it to incremental crawls (Crawl new folders only).

```
aws glue update-crawler 
    --name <crawlername> 
    --recrawl-policy '{"RecrawlBehavior": "CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY"}' 
    --schema-change-policy '{"UpdateBehavior":"LOG","DeleteBehavior":"LOG"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's supported now:

```
Crawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      ...
      ...
      RecrawlPolicy:
        RecrawlBehavior: CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY
```

Also consider that if `CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY` is set, then the only schema change behaviour available is LOG for update or delete.